# How to share parameters across Jenkins jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a folder that contains jenkins jobs to build, test, and deploy the code, and all these jobs share the following parameters:

1. Git branch name. Build trigger from Gerrit which I also have to specify the branch name;
2. Additional build flags;

Item 1 above is used in the Jenkins configuration web GUI where I have to specify the git repo and branch, and also used in the pipeline script where the code is checked out to the named branch.

Can I add any property to a folder and used it as a parameter for ALL the jobs inside that folder? For example, making the branch name a folder property and share it across the jobs.

Comment: This is not possible as far as I am aware.  You could probably write your own plugin using the Jenkins SDK to accomplish this though.  You can set properties at the folder level ( that are injected into the pipelines as env variables ) with the following plugin, but as far as I am aware you cannot add parameters https://plugins.jenkins.io/folder-properties/

Comment: have you already tried setting these to env vars and doing `envsub`s on each of these docs for them?

Comment: @croakPedlar how to set these parameters in env vars and use them to trigger builds? I only know how to set them via pipeline script.

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli how do people manage multiple jobs with the same parameters? for example, 10 jobs using the same branch name to check out and some common build flags, etc. Do we have to specify the same branch name for each job? What if the branch name changed later?

Comment: If all pipelines are checking out from the same repo we would create one declarative Jenkinsfile at the root of the repo ( same file in each branch ).  In the declarative pipeline we would specify one parameter ( branch ) and default it to whatever branch you want to default it to.  Then we would create N number of pipelines and use the declarative Jenkinsfile we just created ( so now the branch param is managed by the Jenkinsfile ).  Then in all N pipelines we would go in the GUI and add the build_flags param and in each pipeline they would be slightly different.

Comment: That way the declarative Jenkinsfile manages the the branch param, but the build_flags param is actually configured in the GUI.  So if you want to default to a different branch you change the Jenkinsfile once and commit to your repo the changes, but if you want to change the build_flags you have to go in each pipeline via the Jenkins GUI and make the changes there.  If you add the build_flags param to the Jenkinsfile and set no default, even if you add a default via the web GUI it will overwrite it with a blank str next execution

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMaggiulli I'm not so familiar with using a Jenkinsfile. What if my jenkins job is already a pipeline type job and has its own script to run? If I use a Jenkinsfile in my code base then I assume that Jenkins will automatically pick the pipeline defined in that Jenkinsfile to checkout the branch (if that's the only thing that I have in that file), is it going to continue running my script pipeline after checking out the code? Does it always run Jenkinsfile pipeline first then switch to the script pipeline afterwards, even if they have the same named stage, e.g. "Test"?

Comment: This is hard to explain in short form.  Best-practice is to create a declarative Jenkinsfile and keep it in the root of your project ( so each branch in your repo will have the same Jenkinsfile ).  In the Jenkinsfile you can specify ( with code ) your parameters ( but in this case you only want to specify the branch param for the reason i listed above ).  Then in the Jenkins you create a pipeline and you add ${branch_name} to the branch configuration.  Then you run it once ( it will fail ) and the jenkinsfile will apply the parameter to your pipeline.  You dont need to specify the

Comment: checkout or clone in the Jenkinsfile because it will already be checking out from that repository/branch.  It is hard to explain in 500 characters or less.  Take a look at some of my previous answers on StackOverflow and it might give you an idea of how to structure this

Comment: Thanks! You can write your full answer below if you want.